# can run application coding in C# in wp8 on phone with wp7 operating system?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sdk

i programming my application with C# , Wp8 and SDK 8. my application can install and run on phone that have Wp7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. You can run your app on a Device running Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 OS. But you can not run your WP8 app on Windows Phone 7 device.

Comment: i use sqlCE 3.5 also. can not install some package in device with windows phone 7 that capable it run?

Comment: Try this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HXl5BhV9jc&list=PLJkyrBcNXvHeMGOGnOQtVwQwfuuz3YnAQ&index=1 
it shows how to install and use SQL CE in WP8 app. This should work for WP7 as well.

Comment: oh no, i say i used sqlce3.5 and wp8 for programing. now what i need to install on my device to make me capable run my application correctly?

Comment: So you have already installed SQL CE and completed your program. NOw you want to install it on a WP8 device and run it? Is that what you want?

Comment: yes you are right. what i have to install in phone now ? am i need install Dotnetframwork or sdk and SQL CE on phone? if yes, do u have any link for download it? very thank you for all your help.

Comment: There is no additional step to install SQL CE on the WP8 device. It is supported by the WP8 OS. You have to just connect the device to the your computer. Make sure you have a developer account and you have developer unlocked the device and then from visual studio select the device as the destination for the deployment and then run the app. The app will then be deployed to the device. Take a look at the following link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your description, but that cell phone device is in other country. i can not use tools or VS.net for deployment my app on device. i have to have another way that independent to me and can easy install on device. have you any idea?

Comment: If the device is developer unlocked (the device you have in another country)  you can get the compiled .xap file and send it to the owner of the phone. Then he/she can install that .xap in to the phone and try it out. But you can not do debugging via this way. only can test to see how it works. Take a look at this link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_tool

Comment: wow, your means: i don't need instal framework or SQL server CE on that device? only xap files enough?

Comment: yup, develop the app, generate the .xap file, send it to the person who has the device and tell him/her to install it using Application Deployment Utility which is installed with the SDK. Thats it..

Comment: thank you again. Application Deployment Utility which is installed with the SDK? he must install SDK on him computer? have u link download of this software (Application Deployment Utility)?

Comment: The SDK have to be installed in the other computer as well. You can not install the Application Download Utility separately. And if the answer to the questions is satisfactory please mark it as correct :)

Comment: but, its not right way. if anyone want install my application, they have to instal SDK on their computer !! anyway very thank you.

Comment: If you want to put the app so people can download it and use it then you have to publish it on the Windows Phone Store. You have to have a developer account set up to do that. Then upload the .xap file created in the Release mode with the description, Screen Shots, Pricing details and with in few hours your app will be available for download for any one.

Comment: take a look at these links..
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/publish#4
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206736(v=vs.105).aspx